# Getting inaccurate distance between two location points in mapbox web

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have been trying to check if the direct distance between the user's current location and the shop's location is less than 4km. But when I move the user's marker, the distance measured seems to be less on the side areas of the shop but a lot more in the vertical up and down space of the shop, which doesn't look proportional as I am expecting a circularly consistent behavior. I have been puzzled with this behavior and can't find the solution. Any help or guidance is sincerely appreciated!

```
<!-- Map Box -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>

<script>

var shop = [18.565461492546987, 73.91061898347883];
var map_msg = document.getElementById('map_msg');

function map_init(lat, long){
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidmR2ZHViZXk3IiwiYSI6ImNrbDVraTNyNDBtZ2EydXBqMnMzamFkZXkifQ.AOlIrevJhdIIK2t5PYIp_A';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
        .setView([lat, long], 13)
        .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));

    var marker2 = L.marker([shop[0], shop[1]], {
        draggable: false,
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'shop',
            'marker-color': '#2F80ED'
        })
    }).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([lat, long], {
        draggable: true,
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'rocket',
            'marker-color': '#2F80ED'
        })
    }).addTo(map);

    function onDragEnd() {
        console.log('hey');
        var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
        console.log('Longitude: ' + lngLat.lng + ' Latitude: ' + lngLat.lat);
    }

    function distance(x, y){
        var to = turf.point([x, y]);
        var from = turf.point([shop[0], shop[1]]);

        var line = turf.lineString([[x, y], [shop[0], shop[1]]]);
        var length = turf.length(line, {units: 'kilometers'});
        console.log(length);

        var options = { units: 'kilometers' };
        var distance_function = turf.distance(to, from, options);
        var distance = turf.distance(from, to, options);

        console.log("Distance: " + distance + " km");
        if(distance > 3){
            map_msg.innerHTML = "Sorry, we don't deliver here!";
            map_msg.style.color = '#FF4E61';
        }else{
            map_msg.innerHTML = "Delivery available in this area";
            map_msg.style.color = '#3D8B18';
        }
    }
    
    distance(lat, long);


    marker.on('dragend', function(e){
        var location = e.target._latlng;
        distance(location.lat, location.lng);
    });


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `var shop = [18.565461492546987, 73.91061898347883];`

Your project is operating at 74 degrees of latitude. In [Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection), at that latitude, there is a significant difference in pixel distance between a degree of latitude and a degree of longitude. (At the equator, there is none).

I haven't inspected your code further, but I imagine it is operating correctly - a squished ellipse is what you would expect. You can verify this by moving your shop to `[0, 0]` and seeing if it gives the circle you were expecting.